# Facebook friends graph api v14.0 - curl

Tags: facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

I am trying to do a PoC to find friends using the same app. I have created an application and am working with test users provided in the facebook app portal.

I have made 2 test users friends, and have given user_friends permission access to the app.

I am using the following command:
`curl -i -X GET  "https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/me/friends?access_token=user_token"`

As a result, I am getting the following result:

```
{"data":[],"summary":{"total_count":1}}
```

Now even if both the test users are friends on facebook, are using the app, and have provided user_friends access to the app, why is it still not returning the other test user in the data.

Would be grateful to get any guidance here